Extra attributes from the server: fdprocessedid at input In Graphql and JSON not updated
I am using Next.js , typescript and Graphql. I am trying to implement add data to a local json file over apollo server. Having 2 issues

I am getting the warning " Extra attributes from the server: fdprocessedid  at input " .

At the moment , console says data added, however JSON file , which is local is not updated.
Here is the resolver.ts
let lastUserId = 0;
Mutation: {
   createUser: (_parent:null,  { input }: { input: AddUserInput }): User =>  {
      const newUserId = ++lastUserId; 
      return {
         id: newUserId.toString(), // Example: generate a random ID
         name: input.name,
         email: input.email,
       };
   }



Schema
input AddUserInput {
  name: String!
  email: String!
}
  type Mutation {
    createUser(input: AddUserInput!): User! 
  }

Component
"use client"
import { FC, FormEvent, useState } from 'react';
import { Action, Contact } from './reducer/userReducer';
import { InputLabel , FormGroup ,TextField,FormControl,Button } from '@mui/material';
import { useMutation, gql } from '@apollo/client';


const ADD_USER = gql`
  mutation AddUser($input: AddUserInput!) {
    createUser(input: $input) {
       id     
           }
  }
`;
  const UserForm: React.FC = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  
    const [addUserMutation] = useMutation(ADD_USER);
  
    const handleSubmit = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      try {
        await addUserMutation({
          variables: {
            input: {
              name,
              email,
            },
          },
        });
        // Optionally, clear the form fields
        setName('');
        setEmail('');
        console.log('User added successfully!');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error adding user:', error);
      }
    };

  return (
    <form  className='userform' onSubmit={handleSubmit} > 
     
      <FormControl fullWidth margin="normal">
        <InputLabel  htmlFor="firstName">First Name</InputLabel >
        <TextField
          className='name'
          name='name'
          value={name}
          type='text'
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
         
        /> 
      </FormControl >
       <FormControl fullWidth margin="normal">
      <InputLabel htmlFor="email">Email</InputLabel>
        <TextField
          className='email'
          name='email'
          value={email}
          type='text'
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          
        /> 
      </FormControl>
      <FormGroup > 
        <Button variant="contained" type="submit">Add        
        </Button>
      </FormGroup>
    </form>
  );
};

export default UserForm;

JSON
   [
    { "id": 1, "name": "Alice", "email": "alice@example.com" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Bob", "email": "bob@example.com" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Bobbb", "email": "bobbb@example.com" }
  ]


i solved the warning by disabling one extension in my browser, called McAfee® WebAdvisor,
im getting the mentioned warning in my input  and buttons, however i solved both the warnings by disabling the McAfee® WebAdvisor extension.
hope it will help
